# Access photos only from select albums on all my devices

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, sharing, photos.app

I would like the ability to view photos grouped under two "People" (two children, say) in Photos 3.0 on all of my Apple devices. Basically I take new photos with my iPhone and occasionally sync them over to my MacBook. I want to view all photos in those two albums on the iPhone (when visiting relatives, say).

I don't want to upload *all* of my photos to iCloud, so *iCloud Photo Library* does not seem to be the right option.

I want the ability to view all photos from those two albums (people) on my devices, so *My Photo Stream* (which covers only recent photos) also does not seem to be the right option.

I want to "share" these photos with myself, not necessarily with others, so *iCloud Photo Sharing* does not seem to be the right option either?

Is there native support in macOS and iOS for what I want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I was halfway stuck between an older way of doing things (sync) and a newer (cloud). The older way still offers selecting individual albums (e.g. for the two faces) for syncing between two devices.

Photos apparently still makes lots of mistakes in assigning photos to albums (as is its want) and therefore the result is still less than optimal overall, but it is probably the right way for me to go.